# how to save value for each iteration and populate html rows accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Requirement is to save the value of each iteration and load values accordingly into html rows.
**Dynamic response from server**:(based on user selection of key)                                                                                    `Key:"Apple"  values:0:Array[2] 1:"500" 1: Array[2]0:""1:"765"` `"Key:"Orange"  values:0:Array[2] 1:"600" 1: Array[2]0:""1:"458"`
Calculation for summing up the total profit value has to be done and value must be saved for every iteration and to be displayed in table.
For eg: For apple the total will be 500+765

[The calculated total value should be displayed in accordance with the key value. The key value will be dynamic based on user selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZSfM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific?
You want to dynamically build a table with the objects you receive from the server?
Is he response an objects' array?

Comment: Yes i have to populate the rows based on the value received from server.

Comment: Can you please provide some html and js code? it should be much easier to figure out what you exactly need and find a solution =)